Finite inversive planes and $PSL_2(q)$
Example 6.2.4 of Dixon and Mortimer's, Permutation groups introduces inversive planes as Stainer systems. The classical (real) inversive plane can be naturally understood as a one-point extension of the Euclidean (affine) plane (i.e. the Riemann sphere), in this case the action of $PSL_2(\mathbb{C})$ as Möbius transformations is clear.
I am aware of the construction of (finite) inversive planes as block systems using the points in an ovoid in $PG(3,q)$ but I was wondering:

Is there an analogous construction of an inversive plane as a one point extension of the affine plane over a finite field? If so, what are the blocks in terms of the affine structure.

In Dixon and Mortimer's is mentioned that $PSL_2(q)$ actis naturally in an inversive plane. I just don't see how. If this is the analogous to the real case, what plays the role of $\mathbb{C}$?



I have voted to reopen this question. I don't think we should close questions just because they contain more than one sentence ending with a question mark. Here the questions are so closely related that it would be unnatural to answer one without answering the other. Moreover, the question was closed well after I posted an answer that I feel is complete.

Dixon--Mortimer surely mean that $\mathrm{PGL}_2(q^2)$ acts naturally, not $\mathrm{PGL}_2(q)$, in which case it is clear that $E = \mathbb{F}_{q^2}$ is playing the role of $\mathbb C$.
Suppose we identify the affine plane over $K = \mathbb F_q$ with $E$. Add a point called $\infty$. Extend the natural inversion map $z \mapsto z^{-1}$ of $E \setminus\{0\}$ to $E \cup \{\infty\}$ by defining $0^{-1} = \infty$ and $\infty^{-1} = 0$. Then $G = \mathrm{PGL}_2(E)$ acts on $E \cup \{\infty\}$ by Möbius transformations. Take the blocks to be the smallest $G$-invariant set containing all the sets of the form $\ell \cup \{\infty\}$, where $\ell$ is a line in the affine plane.
We must check that if a block contains $\infty$ then it has the expected form $\ell \cup \{\infty\}$. Take such a block $(\ell \cup \{\infty\})^g$, $g \in G$. If $\infty^g = \infty$ then $g$ is an affine map and we are done.
Otherwise $u^g = \infty$ for some $u \in \ell$. By composing with a translation we may assume $u = 0$ and $g$ has the form $z^g = a/z + b$. By composing with another translation and a dilation we may assume $g$ is actually just inversion $z^g = 1/z$. Then $\ell = \ell_v = \{v x : x \in K\}$ for some $v \in E$ and $(\ell \cup \{\infty\})^g = \ell_{v^{-1}} \cup \{\infty\}$, as required.
Now we claim the blocks form an $S(3, q+1, q^2+1)$ system. Take a triple of points $u, v, w$. By acting with $G$ we may assume $w = \infty$. There is a unique line $\ell$ of the affine plane passing through $u$ and $v$, so we are done.
